# How to locate and install Great_Expectations .JAR file in Azure Synapse WorkSpace

Tags: apache-spark, azure-synapse, great-expectations

I'm trying to locate and upload Great_Expectations .JAR file to Azure Synapse via Azure Synapse Studio, to update Apache Spark

[image]

I would normally upload a requirements.txt manually via Apache Spark Pool 'Packages' but I'm having problems doing that, therefore attempting to upload a .JAR file.

Can someone let me know where I can find the Great_Expectations.JAR file?

Alternatively, can someone show me where I can find the Python Wheel file or Workspace Package for Great_Expectations please

Comment: ok, I found the Great_Expectations wheel package and uploaded it into Apache Spark but I'm still getting the error ```ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'great_expectations'``
Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Administrators you can close this because the answer to my question can be found here

https://pypi.org/project/great-expectations/#files

Thanks anyway